# Program abort if I make an iterator from a getter

Tags: c++, iterator, getter

This is one weird behavior that I don't understand I have.

I have a class a with a list, and a getter on it :

```
class A
{
  private:
   std::list<OtherClass *> l;
  public:
   std::list<OtherClass *> getL()
   {
     return l;
   }
}
```

Then, if I do something like :

```
A inst;
std::list<OtherClass *>::iterator itB = inst.getL().begin();
std::list<OtherClass *>::iterator itE = inst.getL().end();
for (; itB != itE; ++itB) // Instant ABORT !
```

But if I do :

```
A inst;
std::list<OtherClass *> l = inst.getL();
std::list<OtherClass *>::iterator itB = l.begin();
std::list<OtherClass *>::iterator itE = l.end();
for (; itB != itE; ++itB) // It works now !
```

Can somebody explain to me why is this happening please ? Why have I to go through a temporary variable like this to not abort ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your getter to return a *reference* to the underlying list.

```
std::list<OtherClass *> &getL()
                        ^
```

Without an ampersand it returns a *copy* of the list each time you call it. Consequently, `itB` and `itE` end up being iterators from different lists. And if that's not bad enough, those two lists are temporaries which will have been destroyed by the time the `for` loop begins!

To match this if you use `l` you should make it a reference variable, too.

```
std::list<OtherClass *> &l = inst.getL();
```

Comment: I'd provide a const and a non-const version of the getter. Or maybe only the const one, if modification is not desired.

Answer (score 5):

While all other answers suggest **modifiable references** as the return value, I'd make them **const**:

```
const std::list<OtherClass *> &getL() const;
```

Also I made the function itself const, meaning that it doesn't modify the object itself. Thus you have a **correct *getter method*** (it should neither modify the object nor return a modifiable reference).

You might want to introduce a second version of such a getter function which *can* modify the attribute (if we don't want to hide some code which needs to get executed if that attribute changes, like updating some related thing):

```
std::list<OtherClass *> &getL();
```

However, as already indicated, in some cases this version isn't what you want. If you have to do something in a setter method you don't want to expose the modifiable reference for that attribute. The caller would have to call the getter as seen above, modify the value and call the setter. However, for big data structures like lists, vectors, maps etc, this can be slow, so you might want to introduce single element setters like: `setLAt(int index, OtherClass *value);`

Comment: Exactly, and if for some reason it is desired to modify the list directly, providing a second non-const getter is also possible.

Comment: @leemes Thank you very much for the technical advices !

Answer (score 3):

All the answers so far tell you how to do it correctly, but I thought I'd give you some more details why your code does not work. So as others have pointed out, your "getter" is returning the list by value. This is something specific to (mainly) C++: You, the programmer, have to specify explicitly whether you want to pass an object by value or by reference. Other programming languages, like e.g. Java, will (almost) always pass by reference. Let's say you assign a variable like this:

```
MyClass a;
MyClass b = a;
```

In many languages, the assignment will mean: Make `b` a reference pointing to `a`. You will then be able to invoke methods on `b`, and it will behave just as if it was `a`.

In C++, on the other hand, it means: "Create a second object `b`, then copy all of `a`'s state into `b` (Ignoring the possibility that MyClass has a copy constructor, which is not relevant for this explanation). Now for lists, this means that every element will be copied into a newly created list! (Which can be a performance problem, besides the other implications).

If, on the other hand, you tell the compiler to make a reference to a:

```
MyClass& b = a;
```

Then this `b` will indeed behave as if it was a. No state will be copied, and changing `b` will change `a`.

Ok, now back to your code examples. In the first version, you have the following line:

```
// Creates an invalid iterator!
std::list<OtherClass *>::iterator itB = inst.getL().begin();
```

That's actually a bunch of different stuff there. The call to `inst.getL()` will create a new list and copy all the contents of `inst`'s list member into it. Then, it will obtain an iterator to that copy. Afterwards, the copy itself is destroyed, and the iterator will become invalid. Why? Because you do not assign the list's copy to anything. In C++, a stack allocated object (i.e. not created using `new`) that goes out of scope will be destructed. Simply speaking, "out of scope" happens as soon as the object is not accessible anymore by it's name:

```
{ // Begin scope
    MyClass o; 
    // Inside the braces, it's possible to refer to o:
    o.doSomething();
} // End scope
o.doSomething() // Will be an error, as o is not "known" anymore
```

Which also happens if you discard the return value of a function, like writing:

```
inst.getL();
```

This will create a copy of your list, then destroy it again.

Now, why does your second example work? Because you assign the list's copies to tempory variables, so they stay in scope:

```
std::list<OtherClass *> l = inst.getL();
```

The temporary object from the "getter" call is stored into `l` (ignoring assignment operators, RVO etc. for now), and all iterators obtained for `l` will now be valid until `l` goes out of scope.

```
std::list<OtherClass *>::iterator itB = l.begin(); // valid
```

So this works, although probably not as you expected: The iterators are operating on a copy of your list, not on the actual data. Which sometimes might be what you want - but in your case, you want a reference as suggested by the other answers.

Hope this helped clear it up a bit for you.

Comment: This is a very nice explanation ! Even if I know most of what you explained, this is a very nice reminder for beginners or for those who used to code in C/C++ and have memory leaks. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try update:

```
std::list<OtherClass *> getL()
```

to

```
std::list<OtherClass *>& getL()
```

Note your`inst.getL().begin();` and `inst.getL().end();` return a new copy of list each time

Answer (score 1):

Because every time you call `getL()` then a new `list` is created and the information in the returned value is copied into it.

```
std::list<OtherClass *>::iterator itE = inst.getL().end();
```

Something to also note, is that when you call it like this then you end up with a temporary `list` that destructs at the end of the line. Making the iterator invalid.

Comment: A new A is created ? Or just copies of the list of the original A are ?

Comment: Why is an `A` created? You mean a new list is created (a copy of the attribute the getter wants to return by value)

Comment: @leemes That's what I think too, a new A created each time would be so huge !

Comment: @Florian Sorry about that, a new list is created

Answer (score 1):

The getter returns a *copy* of the list. The list dies at the end of the line, and the iterator is invalid.

You probably mean to return a *reference* to the existing list:

```
std::list<OtherClass *> & getL() { return l; }
//                     ^^^
```